# Override this function, it return previous page, but at same time it will exit the app. Just press the back button once,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onGoBack = this.onGoBack.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onGoBack);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onGoBack);
  }

  onGoBack = () => {
    Alert.alert("jiifwff");

    console.log("ahbjhavf");

    ToastAndroid.show("Back button is pressed", ToastAndroid.SHORT);

    return true;
  };
}
```

Comment: A blob of unformatted code and a vague question in the title is not how this site works. See [ask]. [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, show what you have tried, and tell us what results you get.

Comment: Pls solve this issue i want a expected result ..when i press back button the app is exit not goto the previous screen..i want that when i press back button the previous screen will open the all pure not exit

Comment: If you want to clarify the question, you should [edit] it and put these details in the text so we can all read it. Comments can be deleted, and SO is not a threaded forum. The idea is that you _ask_ a question and volunteers help you figure answers out. However, in this case it looks like you might need to check out some JS tutorials. Ask yourself what happens when `onGoBack` returns to the event handler?

Comment: Are you using React Navigation? If so you may want to use this small library: https://github.com/vonovak/react-navigation-backhandler

Comment: No am not using React Navigation..

Comment: Please anyone help me today is my deadline of this task.

Comment: It is not a good idea to demand an answer from strangers because of _your_ deadline. That is not what this site is about. Did you ask yourself what happens when the `onGoBack` returns to the event handler? This seems pretty straightforward, though I've tried my best to not ever write raw JS event handlers.

Comment: When i click on onGoBack press nothing happend....